# Common title for side by side plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

Let's consider very simple plot and try to name it

```
library(ggplot2)
plot_1 <- ggplot() + aes(x = 1:10, y = 1:10) + geom_line()
patchwork::wrap_plots(plot_1, plot_1, plot_1, ncol = 1, nrow = 3) + ggtitle("a")
```

However, this code will only name the very last plot:

[image]

Is there any possibility that I can have a name for whole plot and not for only the last one ? i.e. to have a name in the place of black rectangle

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want `plot_annotation`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
plot_1 <- ggplot() + aes(x = 1:10, y = 1:10) + geom_line()
wrap_plots(rep(list(plot_1), 4), ncol = 2, nrow = 2) + 
  plot_annotation(title = "a")&
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: That's great! How can I center it ? ;))